# How to get access the corporate docker hub inside docker-in-docker?

Tags: docker, proxy, docker-in-docker

I have a corporate proxy and docker registry(nexus). When I execute the command:
`docker login -u <corporate_login> -p <pass> https://nexus-corporate.com`, 
I get a successful connection. But when I use docker-in-docker image and execute a similar command, there are problems with proxy. How to solve problem?

Error message:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html><head>
    <meta type="copyright" content="Copyright (C) 1996-2018 The Squid Software Foundation and contributors">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved</title>
    <style type="text/css"><!--
     /*
     * Copyright (C) 1996-2018 The Squid Software Foundation and contributors
     *
     * Squid software is distributed under GPLv2+ license and includes
     * contributions from numerous individuals and organizations.
     * Please see the COPYING and CONTRIBUTORS files for details.
     */

    /*
     Stylesheet for Squid Error pages
     Adapted from design by Free CSS Templates
     http://www.freecsstemplates.org
     Released for free under a Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 License
    */

.....

    body
    :lang(fa) { direction: rtl; font-size: 100%; font-family: Tahoma, Roya, sans-serif; float: right; }
    :lang(he) { direction: rtl; }
     --></style>
    </head><body id=ERR_ACCESS_DENIED>
    <div id="titles">
    <h1>ERROR</h1>
    <h2>The requested URL could not be retrieved</h2>
    </div>
    <hr>

    <div id="content">
    <p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="http://docker:2375/v1.40/auth">http://docker:2375/v1.40/auth</a></p>

    <blockquote id="error">
    <p><b>Access Denied.</b></p>
    </blockquote>

    <p>Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect.</p>

    <p>Your cache administrator is <a href="mailto:admin@my_company.com?subject=CacheErrorInfo%20-%20ERR_ACCESS_DENIED&amp;body=CacheHost%3A%20proxy.my_company_domain%0D%0AErrPage%3A%20ERR_ACCESS_DENIED%0D%0AErr%3A%20%5Bnone%5D%0D%0ATimeStamp%3A%20Mon,%2027%20Jan%202020%2008%3A39%3A45%20GMT%0D%0A%0D%0AClientIP%3A%2010.16.11.54%0D%0A%0D%0AHTTP%20Request%3A%0D%0APOST%20%2Fv1.40%2Fauth%20HTTP%2F1.1%0AUser-Agent%3A%20Docker-Client%2F19.03.5%20(linux)%0D%0AContent-Length%3A%2084%0D%0AContent-Type%3A%20application%2Fjson%0D%0AHost%3A%20docker%3A2375%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A">admin@my_company.com</a>.</p>
    <br>
    </div>

    <hr>
    <div id="footer">
    <p>Generated Mon, 27 Jan 2020 08:39:45 GMT by proxy.my_company_domain (squid/4.4)</p>
    <!-- ERR_ACCESS_DENIED -->
    </div>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: Can you describe your problem a little bit more? Is there an exact error message?

Comment: I added more information.

Comment: It say's `access denied`. Are you authenticated successfully?

Comment: `docker login -u <corporate_login> -p <pass> https://nexus-corporate.com`command works successfully, but not docker-in-docker

Comment: This is part of the problem. The main problem - build docker image as part of gitlab CI/CD pipeline.